# How to assign two different sections to a single part on abaqus

Tags: abaqus

I have modelled a cube and i have a cylinder inside the cube. I want to assign two different sections for the cube and the cylinder. I am unable to select the cylinder to assign a section. The whole cube gets selected always. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The part must be partitioned into multiple regions and each one assigned the appropriate section.

If the part is 2D (for which the section would define the thickness), you will partition the face by any method that results in multiple faces

If the part is 3D, you must create cell partitions, since a region of a 3D solid is a cell. This can be done by `tools-->partition`, type: cell. To define more complicated regions, `shape-->shell--->extrude`, create a shell from sketch to extrude through the part (keep internal boundaries), then remove any face that isn’t part of a cell.